# Find the IP from which a person tried to reset Gmail password

Tags: gmail, password-recovery, ip-addresses

Yesterday I received 2 SMS from my Gmail account. Somebody tried to login to my account. He/she tried to use SMS to reset my password. Can anybody tell me how to find the IP from which the attacker sent the password recovery SMS?

I didn't get any email from the Gmail team. I could easily login with my previous password after the attack.

Answer (score 6):

To see the IP addresses and access methods for your Gmail account, you probably want to look at the [Last account activity](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=45938) page.

This page is accessed by the "Details" link at the bottom of the gmail web page.

[image: How to access Gmail's last account activity page]

I'm not sure there is a way to find out the originating IP of a password recovery request, however it is very unlikely that your gmail account was compromised via the [SMS recovery method](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=152124&from=148360&rd=1).

For this to happen, the attacker would have had to somehow login to your account (know your password in the first place), then update your recovery options and change the phone number.

So the good news is that your account is probably still secure, and you got an SMS message from google which alerted you that someone tried to use SMS password recovery and probably failed, as long as they have no access to your phone or SMS messages.

Comment: I tried this. This shows login info. But the person couldn't login rather then sending two sms reset code. Can I find from which IP the person used to do that job? Sorry for the delay.

Comment: As far as I've been able to gather, Google does not provide a way for users to get the IP from which a password reset request comes from.